# click() not working in rails 3.2.1 - Auto Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am building an application using Rails 3.2.6 and I want to create functionality that enables a part of a page reload itself automatically after some time interval. This is what I have done:

1. I created a partial called _hottest_beep where the reloaded content should be
2. I called the partial in main page like so

   ```
   <div class="update_beep">
   <%=render :partial=>"hottest_beeps"%>
   </div>
   ```
3. I created a main.js.erb file

   ```
   $(".update_beep").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("hottest_beeps"))%>")
   ```
4. I added a link on the main page that when that link is clicked the partial reloads automatically

   ```
   <span ><%=link_to'View',{:controller=>'users',:action=>'main'},:remote=>true,:class=>'auto_click'%>
   </span>

   <div class="update_beep">
   <%=render :partial=>"hottest_beeps"%>
   </div>
   ```
5. Then I created a JavaScript file called `auto_click` which will automatically click it every 1sec

   ```
   var fsecs = 1000;

   function feedTimer1()
   {

       if (fsecs == 0)
       {
           $('.auto_click').click();
           fsecs =1000;
           self.status = fsecs
           ftimerRunning = true
           ftimerID = self.setTimeout("feedTimer1()")
       }
       else
       {
           self.status = fsecs
           fsecs = fsecs - 1
           ftimerRunning = true
           ftimerID = self.setTimeout("feedTimer1()")
       }
   }


    window.onload = feedTimer1();
   ```

But is seems like the click even doesnt work. When I load up the page the partial remains the same, but when I click the link my self it works.

Note: I also called the auto_click.js file in the application.html.erb file which should load it to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your js, but this should work:

```
$(function() {
  function tick() {
    $(".auto_click").click();
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }
  tick();
};
```

On a sidenote, you shouldn't be doing a setTimeout from within the function, as you *will* end up piling requests. Let me know if you need code for this.

Edit: For that, you can use this:

```
$(function() {
  window.auto_click_tick = function() {
    $(".auto_click").click();
  }
  window.auto_click_tick();
};
```

and in your js.erb file, add this

```
setTimeout(window.auto_click_tick, 1000);
```

Comment: So why wouldn't you choose to use *setInterval* something like this: `setInterval(function() { $(".auto_click").click(); }, 1000)`

Comment: @ChrisMoutray Yes, it would be the same in this case, but I would want this implementation to be changed slightly, to set the timeout after the request is complete, not after the request is sent.

Comment: Did you mean to use *setInterval* as part of that edit otherwise it will only execute *tick* once and not every second?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray nope, the js.erb will set a timeout after it has modified the content. This way, if the server is slow, and takes like 1 second to respond, this will make sure the client sends requests slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping. But After many hours of work i eventually solved it. The problem was that my jquery file had a bug. changing it solved the problem :)